What is the current research situation of the Cheeger–Goresky–MacPherson conjecture?
In [CGM-1983], J. Cheeger, M. Goresky and R. MacPherson  conjectured that the intersection cohomology of a singular complex projective algebraic variety $X$ is naturally isomorphic to its $L^2$-
cohomology for the metric induced on $X^\text{reg}$ by the Fubini–Study metric of any projective embedding, and this induces a natural Hodge decomposition. Furthermore, the Kähler package holds
for them.
$$\hspace{-2cm}
    \begin{array}{rcl}
        {H_{(2)}^{i}({\mathscr{X}}^\text{reg}) }    &  {\xrightarrow[]{\phantom{aaaa}\cong\phantom{aaaa}}}  &~~~    {\left(IH_{i}^{\overline{m}} (\mathscr{X})\right)^{\hspace{-0.12cm}\ast}}.
    \end{array}$$
There are three questions in my mind about this conjecture as follows.

What is the current research situation of the Cheeger–Goresky–MacPherson conjecture?

Takeo Ohsawa claimed to have proven the conjecture. But in the subsequent literature, it seems to say that this is still a conjecture. I'm not sure if there's a gap in [Oh-1992]. So can someone tell me with certainty where the gap is located here?

If this problem is solved, what different mathematical advancements will it bring？


